# Running json_query() on nested json list and dictionary

Tags: json, ansible

Trying to run a query in ansible playbook.
How do I get the "Names" of items whose corresponding "severity" value is medium, data as below:

```
[
        [
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-13307",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-13304",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-13305",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-13295",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-13297",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-13391",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-13300",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-15140",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-13306",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-11597",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-11598",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2020-10251",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2020-3910",
                "Severity": "high",
                "fix_version": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2020-3909",
                "Severity": "high",
                "fix_version": null
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2018-20225",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2013-2099",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": "3.3.2-r1, 3.2.5-r1, 2.6.8, 2.7.3-r1"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2019-9740",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": "2.7.172.7, 3.5.73.5, 3.6.93.6, 3.7.43.7"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "Name": "CVE-2020-8492",
                "Severity": "medium",
                "fix_version": null
            }
        ]
    ]
```

When trying with *json_query('[[].?Severity==`medium`].Name')* , I get below error:

```
fatal: [asd]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nBad jmespath expression: Unknown token ?:\n[[].?Severity==`medium`].Name\n    ^"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to `"[*][? Severity == 'medium' ].Name"`.

The way above pattern works is, `[*]` matches all the elements in the first list then [? Severity == 'medium' ] filters elements within the elements from first list using `Severity == 'medium'`. Finally `.Name` is returning value of `Name` from second filtered lists.

Answer (score 0):

well worked it out, the dict i had above was generated from another json_query(). 
i had do add a "| flatten" in the end of that query to remove dict brackets and then i was able to query dict.